# Why can't I get Amazon Cognito to accept a token from Google+?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm doing this all within web pages via javascript.

First I send the user to Google so they can grant access:

```
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=token&scope=profile&redirect_uri=https://example.com/&client_id=1414xxxxxxxx-{myclientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

After granting access they are redirected back to my site with something like this:

```
    https://example.com/#access_token={their_token}&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

Then I take that information and provide it to Amazon like so:

```
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:{my-pool-id}',
            Logins: {
                'accounts.google.com': "{their_token}"
            }
    });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("ID: "+identityId:AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
        }
    });
```

And there is where I always end up with an error in the console:

```
"Error: Invalid login token."
```

The identity pool 'us-east-1:{my-pool-id}' is setup in my Amazon Console with the Authentication provider 'Google+' setup and a Google Client ID matching the one in the google url (ie. 1414xxxxxxxx-{myclientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com).

I've also tried setting `AccountId` and `RoleArn` in the params to *CognitoIdentityCredentials* but it hasn't helped in this case. **Am I using the `Logins` parameter correctly? What am I missing?**

If I take out the `Logins` parameter or set it to an empty object, I do get an `identityId` which I assume would be associated with an unauthenticated role. **How do I get an identity with an authenticated role using Google APIs as the token provider?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use id_token instead of access_token. More details to obtain an id_token can be found in this documentation : [OpenIDConnect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)